# How to connect server from client in java over internet?

Tags: java, serversocket

I have created two program in java server and client and I connect through localhost but I want to connect client from over the internet all over the world.

```
public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {

        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 1234);

        OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(outputStream);

        dataOutputStream.writeInt(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));

        InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
        DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(inputStream);

        System.out.println(dataInputStream.readUTF());

    }

}

public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1234);

        while(true) {

            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

            InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
            DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(inputStream);

            int a = dataInputStream.readInt();

            OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(outputStream);


            if(a == 1698) 
                dataOutputStream.writeUTF("Welcome Salman");

            else if(a == 1700) 

                dataOutputStream.writeUTF("Welcome Wajeh");

            else if(a == 1694) 

                dataOutputStream.writeUTF("Welcome Farhan");

            else 
                dataOutputStream.writeUTF("Wrong Roll No");

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The same way your browser connect to SO, you should get the IP address of the server and connect to it, this can be done via DNS.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this just by replace the arguments of the line:

```
Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 1234);
```

into the server´s public ip address and the port where the application is running.